# Prior art for speech detection in a data stream

Tags: software, search, mobile-phone, state-of-the-art

Looking for prior art dated before 2010 regarding technology that determines that data being received at a mobile phone is speech if an accelerometer in the phone moves in a certain direction.

The prior art could be non patent or patent literature. I'm more interested to see how much has been published regarding this type of technology.

Comment: Are you looking for prior art to a specific patent? It's difficult to know what could be prior art without seeing the exact wording of the claims.

Comment: Not looking for a specific patent. Trying to get an idea of whether there was existing technology regarding this concept prior to 2010.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very vague question that can be best answered by a google search restricting results by date. I found 136000 results for "voice recognition phone accelerometer" that were prior to 2010. I found a rather interesting article on research directions in 2006: http://machinedesign.com/article/smarter-than-your-average-pushbutton-0607

In general, I'd have to say that this was a major topic of research for many cell makers.